# autofac: registering the same class more than once with different dependencies

Tags: c#, autofac

Given the following heirarchy:
I need to resolve one instance of **`ProducerRepository`** per registered `IParser` dependency when an **`IEnumerable<ISourceRepository<IDatum>>`** is resolved.

```
public class ProducerRepository : ISourceRepository<Data>
{
    public ProducerRepository(IRepository repository)
    {}
}

public interface ISourceRepository<out T> where T : class, IDatum
{}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Repository(IParser parser)
    {}
}

public class ParserTypeOne : IParser {}
public class ParserTypeTwo : IParser {}
```

I need to register `ProducerRepository` as follows.

```
builder.RegisterType<ProducerRepository>()           
.WithParserTypeOne() // how do I specify this as a particular dependency
.As<ISourceRepository<IDatum>();

builder.RegisterType<ProducerRepository>()          
.WithParserTypeTwo() // another type of parser.
.As<ISourceRepository<IDatum>>();

// OR: better still if at all possible...
builder.RegisterType<ProducerRepository>() // one of these for each underlying dependency
.WithEachPossibleTypeOfParser() // one for each dependency
.As<ISourceRepository<IDatum>>();
```

I need to know how to register the class twice, once with each type of dependency, so that when an **`IEnumerable<ISourceRepository<IDatum>>`** is resolved I get a separate instance of ProducerRepository for each different implementation of the parser.

Better still, it would be nice to be able to register a separate `ProducerRepository` for each instance of the parser found in the assembly scan, and add it.

I was hoping not to have to resort to changing the implementation to use `Keyed` or `Meta` registrations as that locks in each dependency and changes the implementation. If that is the only way of doing it, I will accept the answer. *I am hoping for a generic way to register all the possible implementations*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we reduce the problem, you want that :

```
public class Pouet
{
    public Pouet(Foo foo) { }
}
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IBar bar) { }
}
public interface IBar { }
public class Bar1 : IBar { }
public class Bar2 : IBar { }
```

and

```
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Pouet>().AsSelf();
    builder.RegisterType<Foo>().AsSelf();
    builder.RegisterType<Bar1>().As<IBar>();
    builder.RegisterType<Bar2>().As<IBar>();
    IContainer container = builder.Build();

    IEnumerable<Pouet> pouets = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Pouet>>();

    Console.WriteLine(pouets.Count()); // => must return 2 here !
```

Basically, to return more than 1 `Pouet` using `container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Pouet>>()` `container`must have more than 1 registration of `Pouet` same thing for `Foo`. In order to do that, you can make this ugly thing :

```
    // don't do that
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Pouet>().Named<Pouet>("initial");
    builder.RegisterType<Foo>().Named<Foo>("initial");
    builder.Register(c => c.ResolveNamed<Pouet>("initial", TypedParameter.From<Foo>(c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<Foo>>>().Where(m => (Int32)m.Metadata["Bar"] == 1).Select(m => m.Value).First()))).As<Pouet>().WithMetadata("Bar", 1);
    builder.Register(c => c.ResolveNamed<Pouet>("initial", TypedParameter.From<Foo>(c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<Foo>>>().Where(m => (Int32)m.Metadata["Bar"] == 1).Select(m => m.Value).First()))).As<Pouet>().WithMetadata("Bar", 2);
    builder.Register(c => c.ResolveNamed<Foo>("initial",TypedParameter.From<IBar>(c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<IBar>>>().Where(m => (Int32)m.Metadata["Bar"] == 1).Select(m => m.Value).First()))).As<Foo>().WithMetadata("Bar", 1);
    builder.Register(c => c.ResolveNamed<Foo>("initial",TypedParameter.From<IBar>(c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<IBar>>>().Where(m => (Int32)m.Metadata["Bar"] == 2).Select(m => m.Value).First()))).As<Foo>().WithMetadata("Bar", 2);
    builder.RegisterType<Bar1>().As<IBar>().WithMetadata("Bar", 1);
    builder.RegisterType<Bar2>().As<IBar>().WithMetadata("Bar", 2);

    IContainer container = builder.Build();

    IEnumerable<Pouet> pouets = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Pouet>>();

    Console.WriteLine(pouets.Count()); // => 2 !
```

If you add a new intermediate dependency or a new `IBar`, you will have to write a lot of code. Using a custom `IRegistrationSource`, it should be possible to automate these uglies registrations but it will be quite complex and not really efficient.

Another solution would be to play with lifetimeScope :

```
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Pouet>().AsSelf();
    builder.RegisterType<Foo>().AsSelf();
    builder.RegisterType<Bar1>().As<IBar>();
    builder.RegisterType<Bar2>().As<IBar>();

    IContainer container = builder.Build();

    using (ILifetimeScope workScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        List<Pouet> pouets = new List<Pouet>();

        foreach (IComponentRegistration registration in container.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(new TypedService(typeof(IBar))))
        {
            using (ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(cb => cb.RegisterComponent(registration)))
            {
                Pouet pouet = scope.Resolve<Pouet>();
                workScope.Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal(scope);
                pouets.Add(pouet);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(pouets.Count);
    }
```

By the way this code could be used inside an `IRegistrationSource` so you should be able to resolve `IEnumerable<Pouet>()` on your container.

If possible, I would recommend to refactor your code and make it simpler, playing with instance coming from another `ILifetimeScope` could be problematic and I'm not really confident about disposal of these instances : what happens if a type is registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` (I have not tried) ? etc.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response. I had started doing explicit registrations for these services. Thanks for the tips.